# Typographical errors in the Stack Overflow User Survey. ​

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, survey, typographical-error

Tl;dr in the Stack Overflow User Survey, capitalize "Github" as "GitHub" and add a hyphen in "AI-powered".

---

See this screenshot (click for full-res screenshot):

> [image]

However, it's "GitHub" not "Github" (capitalize the "h").

Additionally, later in the survey, there's this:

> How often do you include AI powered tools (i.e. ChatGPT, CoPilot, etc) into your developer workflow?

"CoPilot" is likely capitalized wrong and ambiguous. There's [Microsoft Copilot](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-copilot) and [GitHub Copilot](https://github.com/features/copilot). That word ("CoPilot") should probably be correctly capitalized and ideally replaced with which "copilot" product you intended to refer too. There's a hyphen in "AI-powered" on the page after that [per the Stack Overflow writing guide](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#hyphens).

There should *maybe* be a comma after "i.e." per [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6896) and [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/16215) both on English SE.

Could these errors be fixed?

Comment: "and ideally replaced with which "copilot" product you intended to refer too" This isn't useful to do after significant people have voted already. Keeping the ambiguous name at least makes it transparent that answers are ambiguous.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That's true, and makes sense, but if SE plans to reuse these questions later (next year), changing the text for reuse without changing this survey might be a possibility.

Comment: @cocomac Thanks for flagging. Can you let me know where/when the survey is popping up? Once I get that info, I can work on which team it belongs to and have them take a look.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't really think that's ambiguous in a meaningful way anyway. It's just using it as an example, it's not asking if you're using those exact AI tools.

Comment: @Dalmarus It was at the top of the page on SO somewhere, but I don't recall more than that. It was a link to `https://stackoverflow.com/survey/site-satisfaction/redirect` and that redirected to a `https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com ...` link. The page title after clicking on the survey is "Stack Overflow User Survey". Hopefully that's enough to figure it out.

Comment: @cocomac Thanks for the info! Last question - did you see this today, last week, etc.?

Comment: @Dalmarus March 5th.

Comment: @cocomac Perfect. Thanks! I'll pass this on post any updates in an answer below when I get them.

Comment: @cocomac nice to see you again! Thanks for flagging this. It was an easy fix!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for flagging. Turned out to be a very quick fix that has been implemented now. Woot! Marking as resolved.